# A function induced by the tracial functional

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a $C^*$algebra, $\tau$ is a tracial functional on $M_k(A)$, then it produces a function $d_{\tau}:M_k(A)^{+}\to [0,\infty) $ defined by $d_{\tau}(a)=\lim_{n}\tau(a^{\frac{1}{n}})$.
The sequence in the right side is increasing and bounded above,so the limit exists.

My question is: what is the limit?

Comment: It's a dimension function. Try to find out what happens if $A = \mathbb C$ or $A = C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$.

Comment: So the limit is $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(a)$?

Comment: $d_\tau(a)$ is a real number ... If for example $a \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is a positive matrix, you should verify that $d_\tau(a) = \mathrm{rank}(a)$, where $\tau$ is the unique tracial state on $M_n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Opps,I saw the answer from a lecture video on the net.

Comment: If $a=I_2$,the rank is 2,but the limit is 1.

Comment: It's either going to be $\operatorname{rank}(a)$ or $\operatorname{rank}(a)/k$, depending on whether or not you normalize the trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the algebra $A$ and the tracial state $\tau$.  The general idea is that $d_\tau(a)$ measures the "size" of $a$, relative to $\tau$ if $A$ has multiple traces.  I provide a couple of basic examples which might help to make this more clear.

As pointed out in the comments, if $A=\mathbb C$ and $\tau$ is the unique tracial state on $M_k(\mathbb C)$ then $d_\tau(a)=\operatorname{rank}(a)/k$.

If instead $A=C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$, $k=1$, and $\tau$ is given by some probability measure $\mu\in M(X)$ (by one of the Riesz representation theorems, all tracial states on $C(X)$ arise in this way), then we have $d_\tau(f)=\mu(f^{-1}(0,\infty)).$